# Странное поведение условий if в reactjs render

Tags: reactjs

Пытаюсь отображать блок по условию, а в результате у меня console.log срабатывает и в одном и в другом случае. Как такое возможно? 
Использую ReactJs 16 + Redux.

```
const cntUpFiles = this.props.uploads.uploadsFiles.length;
const upFiles = this.props.uploads.uploadsFiles;
const action = this.props.action;
const uplds = this.props.uploads.uploads;
let fDz = null;

if (cntUpFiles === 0 && action === 'add') {
  console.log(upFiles);
  fDz = this.renderDropzone();
} else if (cntUpFiles > 0 && action === 'edit') {
  console.log(upFiles);
  fDz = this.renderDropzone(upFiles, uplds);
}
```

Подскажите как такое возможно?
Код метода

```
renderDropzone = (uploadsFiles, uploads) => (
  <FileDropzoneField
    name="file"
    uploadFiles={uploadsFiles || []}
    uploadHiddenFieldsFiles={uploads || []}
    placeholder="Добавьте фото"
    validationError="Добавление фотографий обязательно для создания новости"
    validations={{minLength: 1, maxLength: 10}}
    validationErrors={{
      minLength: 'Минимальное количество файлов 1',
      maxLength: 'Максимальное количество файлов 10'
    }}
    required
  />
);
```

а в консоль выводится два раза, что массив заполнен.
[image: Скриншот консоли]

Comment: Вообще, к примеру у Google Chrome имеется очень полезное расширение: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

Comment: Так как вы используете Redux, то я порекомендую вам использовать еще одно расширение, тоже для хрома: Redux DevTools: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=ru

Comment: В связке React Developer Tools и Redux DevTools позволяют досконально отслеживать то, что происходит в `state` и `props`, какие действия были вызваны в Redux, а также что было до и после, что изменилось.

Comment: То есть нужно будет установить вот этот пакет к себе в проект: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-devtools

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что у вас возможен множественный рендеринг. То есть, если меняются `props` или `state` - происходит ререндеринг, поэтому происходит снова проверка. Если взглянуть на ваши перменные:

```
const cntUpFiles = this.props.uploads.uploadsFiles.length;
const upFiles = this.props.uploads.uploadsFiles;
const action = this.props.action;
const uplds = this.props.uploads.uploads;
```

То видно, что у вас здесь используется значние из `props`, соответсвенно, если что-то поменяется в родителе, или в `state` самого компонента - произойдет ререндеринг и вы снова попадете внутрь дочернего компонента и снова будете проходить условия и получите логирование в консоли.

Наколько я понимаю, изначально в `uploadsFiles` ничего нет, точнее пустой массив, затем файлы загружаюся, меняется значение в `this.props.uploads.uploadsFiles` происходит ререндеринг и снова попадаем в условия. Единственное, неизвестно как и где меняется `this.props.action`, но и это явно меняется, так как там ожидается два значения `'add'` или `'edit'`. Код ReactJS работает так, как и ожидается.

Повторюсь: при любом изменении `props` или `state` - происходит ререндеринг, поэтому происходит снова проверка и логирование в консоль, это нормальное поведение для React.

Очень полезно для изучения:

- [React.Component `render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)
- [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
- [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: это сам метод
  `renderDropzone = (uploadsFiles, uploads) => (
    <FileDropzoneField
      name="file"
      uploadFiles={uploadsFiles || []}
      uploadHiddenFieldsFiles={uploads || []}
      placeholder="Добавьте фото"
      validationError="Добавление фотографий обязательно для создания новости"
      validations={{minLength: 1, maxLength: 10}}
      validationErrors={{
        minLength: 'Минимальное количество файлов 1',
        maxLength: 'Максимальное количество файлов 10'
      }}
      required
    />
  );`

Comment: Да, я уже понял) прошу прощения, первый раз на стаке

Comment: @АлексейШипилов комменарии по вопросу можно отсюда удалить.

Comment: А почему тогда в консоли 2 раза отображается заполненый массив, если первый раз он рендериться пустой, а только второй раз заполненный?

Comment: this.props.action меняется при смене url

Comment: @АлексейШипилов - это я предположил по поводу пустого, до того, как вы внесли правку. По поводу отображения заполненного массива дважды, важно помнить, что *при любом изменении `props` или `state` - происходит ререндеринг, поэтому происходит снова проверка и логирование в консоль, это нормальное поведение для React.* Нужно искать место, где меняется `props` или `state`, поведение не странное :)

Comment: Я все равно не понимаю, что происходит...
Первый раз мы заходим в одно ветвление if и там должен вывестись незаполненный массив, второй раз при повторном рендеринге, если меняется например, мы должны зайти во второе ветвление и не заходить в первое, верно же?
Но ведь при повторном рендеринге, он уже заходит в оба условия .